# Cupcake division

Tags: mathematics, optimization

A elementary school student brought cupcakes to their class to celebrate their birthday! However, there's a problem: There are 25 students in the classroom, and only 24 cupcakes!

The students have recently been studying fractions. One of the students quickly puts forth a solution: "Everybody can have 24/25 of a cupcake! We can cut 1/25 off of every cupcake, combine those into one cupcake, and then we'll have 25." However, nobody seems willing to accept a "cupcake" made out of 24 cupcake crumbs.

It is up to you to figure out how to divide the cupcakes in a way that is both fair, and doesn't reduce the treats to pastry dust. What strategy can you use to ensure that **the smallest slice you have to make is as large as possible?**

This puzzle is purely mathematical: Every student must get exactly 24/25 of a cupcake, every cupcake is exactly the same size, the students will wait patiently while you measure and cut the cakes, etc..

---

This puzzle was inspired by a page from [Math Curse](https://books.google.com/books?id=fw0YGQAACAAJ), where the main character faces a similar situation. They resolve it by simply not eating a cupcake, but here you have no such option...

This is my first post on PuzzlingSE, so please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong!

Comment: If I cut every cupcake into twenty-five pieces, then give each student a 1/25th from each cupcake, then _every_ student gets a "cupcake" made out of 24 cupcake crumbs! All fair! Nobody can complain :)

Comment: What a nice first question, welcome to PuzzlingSE!

Comment: @Hugh - but that can't be the optimal crumbiness, because your comment contains no technobabble. Note that we can write 24 as a sum of proper divisors, 24 = 12 + 8 + 3 + 1. Therefore cut 12 cupcakes in half, 8 in thirds, 3 in eighths, and the last cupcake into 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/8 + 1/24. Further divide the leftover 1/24 by 25. Each student gets 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/8 + 1/600 = 24/25, which by the Fibonacci fraction handwave theorem is optimal, QED.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smallest slice would be:

> 8/25 of a cupcake

The procedure I followed was:

> You ultimately need to cut at least one cupcake in 3 pieces, you cannot cut them all in half. Let's cut that one in 3 slices of 8/25,
>  8/25, and 9/25 size. Then you can cut other cupcakes to match the
>  sizes of those parts. For example, if you combine the 8/25 size with a
>  16/25 slice from another cupcake, then you'll have a 24/25 amount of
>  cupcake for one student. That other cupcake with have a 25-16 = 9/25
>  slice left-over. Match that slice with part of yet another cupcake,
>  etc. Working further like that you will be able to give everybody
>  24/25 slices.

This leads to:

> 2 cupcakes divided as: 8-8-9, 4 cupcakes divided as 16-9, and 6 cupcakes each divided as 15-10, 14-11, and 13-12.

And the students get:

> 4 students get slices of sizes 8+16. Slices of sizes 9+15, 10+14, and 11+13 go to 6 students each. And the remaining 3 students get slices of sizes 12+12.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer and i believe that this is also optimal, i will show it when i am back home:

> $\frac{8}{25}$

Let's call a whole cupcake

> 100 unit and what we are aiming is 96 dividing these 100s into pieces

so the obvious answer from the question was

> $4$

so we want as big pieces as it possible, so theoretically

> two of 48 unit pieces would be ideal,

let’s try it

> 48+52 out of 100 units

so what we gonna do with

> 52? let’s find a one piece match to 96, which would be 44, divide a 100 units of cakes into 44 + 56...

and so on

```
100 - 48 52
100 - 44 56
100 - 40 60
100 - 36 64
100 - 32 32 36
100 - 60 40
100 - 56 44
100 - 52 48
```

(
i will talk about why i decided to divide one piece into 3 later, you mah figure out by yourself though) and

> we will have 32 units of cake left after matching up pieces into 96 units.

and we do this 2 more times

> as a result, we have extra three 32 pieces, lastly combine them.

so the answer becomes

> $\frac{8}{25}$

sorry, it is messy but i am on the phone at a camp site, fix it when i am back

Comment: You posted your 8/25 solution 30 minutes before @fishinear, but I thought they explained it better, so I gave them the checkmark. Good answer though!

Comment: @Woofmao interesting, there is no reasoning in that answer at all, i dont understand how you like it to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

My smallest piece is

> $\frac{6}{25}$

You split the cakes as follows:

> $3$ cakes as $\frac{6}{25}+\frac{6}{25}+\frac{6}{25}+\frac{7}{25}$
>  $13$ cakes as $\frac{7}{25}+\frac{9}{25}+\frac{9}{25}$
>  $8$ cakes as $\frac{8}{25}+\frac{8}{25}+\frac{9}{25}$
>  This gives $9$, $16$, $16$, and $34$ pieces of sizes $\frac{6}{25}$ to $\frac{9}{25}$.

Then put them together as

> $9$ cakes of $\frac{6}{25}+\frac{9}{25}+\frac{9}{25}$
>  $16$ cakes of $\frac{7}{25}+\frac{8}{25}+\frac{9}{25}$

Answer (score 1):

How about

> - Cut 19 cupcakes into five fifths each. You have 95 fifths.
>  - Take one fifth out of each of the other 5 cupcakes. You have 100 fifths and 5 leftovers.
>  - Give each student 4 fifths.
>  - Cut the 5 leftovers each into 5 equal pieces. Give each student 1.
>  Each student got the same number of the same sized bits, so it must be fair.

The smallest piece is

> The fifth of the leftover, which would be 4/25 (16%) of a cupcake.

Comment: it seems your answer is the same as mine :) I noticed your late sorry...

Comment: @Oray it's okay, we'll just divide most of our upvotes into fifths, etc etc